If $\alpha\le\beta$ then $\operatorname{cf}(\alpha)\le\operatorname{cf}(\beta)$?
Let be $\alpha$ and $\beta$ ordinals such that the inequality
$$
\alpha<\beta
$$
holds: I know it's possibile the inequality
$$
\operatorname{cf}(\alpha)<\operatorname{cf}(\beta)
$$
does not hold (indeed it's possible $\operatorname{cf}(\alpha)$ and $\operatorname{cf}(\beta)$ are equal, right?) so that I asked myself if the inequality
$$
\operatorname{cf}(\alpha)\le\operatorname{cf}(\beta)
$$
always holds.

Well, to prove the conjecture I tried as to follow: if $f$ is a cofinal map from $\operatorname{cf}(\beta)$ to $\beta$ then for any $y$ in $\alpha$ there exists $x$ in $\operatorname{cf}(\beta)$ such that the inequality
$$
y\le f(x)
$$
holds so that if $g$ is a bijection from $\left|f^{-1}[\alpha]\right|$ to $f^{-1}[\alpha]$ then $f\circ g$ is cofinal in $\alpha$ but the inclusion
$$
f^{-1}[\alpha]\subseteq\operatorname{cf}(\beta)
$$
implies the inequality
$$
\left|f^{-1}[\alpha]\right|\le\left|\operatorname{cf}(\beta)\right|\le\operatorname{cf}(\beta)
$$
so that the inequality
$$
\operatorname{cf}(\alpha)\le\operatorname{cf}(\beta)
$$
is true since $\operatorname{cf}(\alpha)$ is the minimum ordinal cofinal to $\alpha$.

So I ask if the conjecture I advanced is true and so if I proved it correctly: could someone help me, please?

@SassatelliGiulio I think you found an answer to the question: my proof fails because above $f(x)$ could not be in $\alpha$.

$\DeclareMathOperator{\cf}{cf}$
Consider the ordinals $\omega_1$ (the first uncountable ordinal) and $\omega_\omega$ (the first ordinal of cardinality $\aleph_\omega$).
Then

$\omega_1 < \omega_\omega$
$\cf(\omega_1) = \omega_1$ ($\aleph_1$ is a regular cardinal)
$\cf(\omega_\omega) = \omega$ -- the sequence $\omega, \omega_1, \omega_2, \dots, \omega_n,\dots$ of order type $\omega$ is cofinal.

This disproves your conjecture with $\alpha = \omega_1, \beta = \omega_\omega$.
